# Creating objects with a type determined at runtime

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns, io

I am writing a program that needs to save and load various objects from a file. The files are saved as XML, and I have therefore decided to create an interface called "XMLConvertible" for all the classes that can be converted to XML. When I read the file however, I need to create objects of different types depending on the contents of the XML file.

for example:

```
<Component></Component>
<Module></Module>
```

needs to first create an object of type Component, then an object of type Module.

the cleanest way I've encountered so far is to have a Factory with a static list of Builders for all the different classes that can be read from the XML file. Like this (some information has been left out for brevity):

```
public interface XMLConvertible {
    public void write();
    public void read();
}

public abstract class Factory {
    private static Map<String, Builder> xmlConvertibles = new HashMap<>();

    public static void addXmlConvertible(String key, XMLConvertible value) {
        xmlConvertibles.put(key, value);
    }

    public static XMLConvertible getXmlConvertible(String key) {
        return xmlConvertibles.get(key);
    }
}

public class Component implements XMLConvertible {
    ...
}

public class ComponentBuilder extends Builder {
    static {
        Factory.addXmlConvertible("Component", new ComponentBuilder);
    }

    public Component build() {...}
}

public class Module implements XMLConvertible {
    ...
}

public class ModuleBuilder extends Builder {
    static {
        Factory.addXmlConvertible("Component", new ComponentBuilder);
    }

    public Module build() {...}
}
```

the problem with this is that I have to create 2 classes for every new XMLConvertible class I add, an actual class and a builder. I would like to either have a way of forcing myself to add a builder so I don't forget, or ideally find a more clean way to implement something like this.

sorry for the long post, I tried to shorten it a bit. Hopefully it is still easy to understand what the problem is.

Comment: This is an old problem, and has been asked and answered many times. But I can't find a canonical answer right now.

Comment: You are implementing _serialization_.  Have a look at [this](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/amber/serialization.html)

Comment: please correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I can see, I'd still need to know what class I'm deserializing when reading the XML. Would I then not be left with the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do you care about the format of the XML? There are tools like xstream which will serialise to XML, e.g.

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        XStream xStream = new XStream();

        List<Object> things = new ArrayList<>();
        things.add(new Component("foo"));
        things.add(new Module("bar"));

        String xml = xStream.toXML(things);
        List<Object> things2 = (List<Object>) xStream.fromXML(xml);
    }

    public static class Component {
        private final String componentField;

        public Component(String componentField) {this.componentField = componentField;}
    }

    public static class Module {
        private final String moduleField;

        public Module(String moduleField) {this.moduleField = moduleField;}
    }
}
```

In your pom you need:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.15</version>
        </dependency>
```

This produces:

```
<list>
  <Example_-Component>
    <componentField>foo</componentField>
  </Example_-Component>
  <Example_-Module>
    <moduleField>bar</moduleField>
  </Example_-Module>
</list>
```

You don't need to write any special builders, *but* the structure of your XML file is identical to the implementation of your classes, so change may be difficult if any cross version compatibility is needed.

Comment: Cross version compatibility is pretty important, but if I can't find another answer I guess this is a place to start. Thanks for the help. I would also prefer to write the solution myself from scratch as my program is just as mutch an exercise for getting better at programming as it is a system I will actually use.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding an abstract Builder to the XMLConvertible interface which will be overridden in all implementations of XMLConvertible. At least this way I don't have to create 2 new files for every new implementation.

```
public interface XMLConvertible {
    public void write();
    public void read();

    public abstract static class Builder {
        public abstract XMLConvertible build([XML data]);
    }
}
```